# Using variadics function in variadics template class

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I'd like to implement a graph where each node has data. However I do not know yet what kind of data I'll get. Therefore I think I should use variadics template to make it. My class `Node` has to perform somethink like this :

```
//in Node.hpp
template<typename Identifier , typename... NodeData>
class Node {
 private:
nodeData... data;
//std::tuple<nodeData...> data;
Identifier ID;

 public:
Node(Identifier nodeID, NodeData... data){
     this->ID = nodeID;
     this->data = data;
}

void set_data(nodeData... data){
    this->data = data;
}

nodeData... get_data(){
//std::tuple<nodeData...> get_data() {
    return this->data;
}
```

But as you may know, it does't work like that, but I have no idea how to make it right. `NodeData` could be pretty much everything, for instance a string and two int.
Moreover, this class is used somewhere else ( in class `Graph`) with functions that looks like

```
//in Graph.hpp
void update_data(Identifier ID, nodeData... data){
    get_Node(ID).Node<Identifier, nodeData...>::set_data(data)
    // get_Node(ID).Node<Identifier, nodeData...>::set_data(data...)
}
```

Does this syntax looks right to you (assuming `set_data` works)?

Thank you in advance for any kind of help/clue,

Ezor

PS : sorry for my bad english

Comment: You can't have a parameter pack as a data member. `NodeData... data;` isn't an acceptable class member. The closest thing might be `std::tuple<NodeData...> data;`.

Comment: Thanks for this super-fast answer !
Do I have to use tuple or is this just a solution among many others? Cause I can't use it here (`'tuple' could not be resolved` error)

Comment: You can always come up with your own solution, but `std::tuple` is designed to contain sets of objects of varying type. See [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple). Be sure to include `#include <tuple>`. It's not as easy to use as other containers, but that's consequence of using variadic templates.

Comment: @Ezor As the Standard way to implement a set of arbitrarily typed objects, `std::tuple` is the natural choice, unless you find some specific reason to use anything else.

Comment: I agree with you. But for some reason `tuple` is "could not be resolved"  although I've included it on beforehand (can't understand so far)

Comment: Post the exact code you wrote and the exact message you got.

Comment: this is the exact code (without all functions of course, but all the others are alike)
I've updated my first post to give you an overview of them.

The message `Symbol 'tupe' could not be resolved` is given by my IDE (Eclipse)

Comment: `tupe`. Think about that for a bit. Also, once you spell it right, it still needs the `std::` namespace qualifier, unless you are `using` that namespace, which you probably shouldn't.

Comment: I did not copy paste that. It is of course `Symbol 'tuple' could not be resolved`, my bad. I also use `std::` before

Comment: I also have couples of `parameter packs not expended with '...'` when I call from `Graph` functions in `Node`

Comment: Ok, so I think I solve some issues, but my `set_data` function does't work. Is there a nice way to store data from the template variable `nodeData` into the tuple (assuming I find out what's wrong with `tuple`?)

Comment: For anyone to stand any chance of answering that, you need to define _"does[n]'t work"_...

Comment: It was just a syntax mistake actually. I didn't know where to add `...`. The answer posted by @Richard Hodges solve this.

Regarding to the "tuple question", it appears that it is just a fake-error return by Eclipse. I don't know what happen, but since I couldn't test my programm before having solve everything else, I was misled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start here. Then think about separating out the types of the constructor arguments and the set_data calls:

```
//in Node.hpp

#include <tuple>

template<typename Identifier , typename... NodeData>
class Node {
private:
    Identifier ID;
    std::tuple<NodeData...> data;

public:
    Node(Identifier nodeID, NodeData... data)
    : ID(nodeID)
    , data { data ... }
    {
    }

    void set_data(NodeData... data){
        this->data = std::tie(data...);
    }

    auto get_data() const {
        return this->data;
    }
};


Node<int, int, float>& get_Node(int id)
{
    // whatever you need to do here
}

//in Graph.hpp
template<class Identifier, class...nodeData>
void update_data(Identifier ID, nodeData... data)
{
    get_Node(ID).set_data(data...);
}

int main()
{
    Node<int, int, float> x = { 10, 1, 2.1 };

    update_data(10, 1, 2.1);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was doing something similar but it's very hepfull to have that.

it's seems that my previous issue about `tuple` was just a fake-error shown by Eclipse. The real problem was the way I set `data`.